# Silverlight tabcontrol with scrollable tabItems

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0, tabcontrol

Hi i am working in Silver light I ran into an issue where I had more tab items than could fit within the desired width of my tab control.  Instead of all the tab items appearing on a single line, they would wrap and create a multiline affect which I did not want.

**1. I wanted the user to be able to scroll through the tab items**

Can you all help with this? please correct my direction and with sample code.

Comment: Just a thought: If you can come up with some way -- ANY way -- of *not* subjecting your users to scrolling through tabs, it would be preferable.  I don't think I've ever seen such a UI, and inventing one of your own is almost always a bad idea and will result in unhappy users.  Rather than tabs, how about a menu based on a treeview or listbox?